# Foundation 5 Data-Interchange background images

Tags: image, background, zurb-foundation, data-interchange

I already have data-interchange images on the page - they work fine.

Now that I want to put a background image in a 'div'  - I can't get it to work.

What actually happens the image will not show until I put some content in the div. And, of course it only shows enough image to cover the block element in front of it.

I'm guessing I have to some custom CSS to fix this. I actually want the div to be content free, but just show the background image/s based on screen size via data-interchange.

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

a little vague but from what you have said. have you tried adding the class

```
.clearfix
```

on the div with your image in.